# What is the Maximum supported Spring Version with JDK 7

Tags: java, spring, java-7

My project requires JDK 7 to build. What is the highest supported Spring version with JAVA 7 that can be used in my project? Is Spring 5.x supports java 7?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Spring 5.x supports java 7?

No, the minimum JDK version that you need for Spring 5.x is JDK 8. Given below is the list of JDK and Spring version mappings:

**JDK Version Range**

```
Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-17 (expected)
Spring Framework 5.2.x: JDK 8-15
Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8
```

Check [Spring Framework Versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions) for more details.